# Do forward, but deny direct incoming connections

Tags: linux, virtualbox, firewall, forwarding, nftables

VM = Virtual Machine.
WS = Workstation VM.
GW = Gateway VM.
Virtualization software: Oracle VirtualBox.
Host/Guest OSes: all Debian 12.
Firewall software: nftables

## Goal

Whonix-like setup. WS sits behind internal adapter, GW sits behind the same internal adapter plus NAT. WS accesses internet through GW.

#### Why not just NAT?

NAT allows connections to host's loopback interface, which is undesirable.

## The problem

Setting up firewall rules. I want to make it so that WS can only forward its traffic through GW, but cannot make direct connections to it.

The reason is I fail to see why it should be otherwise. GW might happen to host some services for other VMs in the same internal network and the WS should not be able to access them.

## What I do understand

It has something to do with the packets' destination. If WS tries to connect to GW directly, the final destination of the packets will be GW's IP address, otherwise the daddr will be pointing elsewhere.

I also know that there is such thing as nexthop which is presumably the pointer that tells where a packet should be sent next.

## What I do not understand

How to setup respecting nftables' rules. Also, my knowledge about how the whole networking thing works is also limited and was obtained through manpages and trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

enp0s3 = internal adapter.
enp0s8 = NAT adapter.
192.168.1.100 = IP address of GW.
192.168.1.1 = IP address of WS.
Settings below belong to GW. WS setup is trivial.

```
/etc/network/interfaces:  

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100/24

auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

```
/etc/nftables.conf:

#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
    set rfc1918 {
        type ipv4_addr; flags interval
        elements = { 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16 }
    }
    chain nat {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat;
        oif "enp0s8" counter masquerade
    }
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop
        ct state established,related counter accept
        counter
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop
        iif  "enp0s3" ip saddr 192.168.1.1 oif "enp0s8" \
          ip daddr != @rfc1918 counter accept
        iif "enp0s8" oif "enp0s3" ip daddr 192.168.1.1 counter accept
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter;
    }
}
```

```
/etc/sysctl.conf:

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

All the above seems to work. As I see it now asking the question could be avoided, but I think it won't hurt if it will be archived here for future reference.

If you find problems with firewall setup or with anything else, please write about it for polishing makes perfect.